# How to restore windows.old for windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I reinstall windows. Then I regret that and want to go back.

Fortunately the old windows is stored at windows.old

I follow the instruction in

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971760

I did it all with small catches

When I insert the windows 7 installer, the drive for installer is X and my hard disk is D rather than C. However, on normal windows operation the drive is C. Only when I boot through CD the partition is assigned to the letter D.

There is no file bootsect on my windows installer

So I can't do

```
**D:\boot\bootsect /nt60 c:**
```

Which should be changed to X:\boot\bootsect /nt60 C: or  X:\boot\bootsect /nt60 D: depending on what it really does. As I said if I boot through windows dvd my hard disk letter is D but normally it's C.

I am not even sure what that bootsect does anyway.

I also can't do this one

**Attrib –h –s –r boot.ini.saved
Copy boot.ini.saved boot.ini**

There is no file boot.ini or boot.ini.saved

It's hidden but I don't see it if I try to look unhidden files either.

Because I simply switch from windows 7 to windows 7 and the directory for windows don't change **c:\windows** I thought it should still work.

Well, it doesn't. When windows restart it only goes to the logo and then restart the computer.

Comment: It might not be possible to reverse your changes to your system.  It is my understanding that Windows.old does not have all the required files once the install indicates to itself it was sucessful.  Why would you install Windows 7 over Windows 7?

Comment: because I messed up the bios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having just gone through this on a friend's Acer Aspire, I am assuming you are using something similar.  Instead of a restore disk there is a restore partition.

You were correct in using the drive letters, just be sure you follow the instructions on that support.microsoft.com website **exactly** with the only exceptions being replacing "c:" with "d:" as you stated above.

**For a boot problem** the following should help you with restore partition software similar to what Acer Aspires are running (again assuming you are running something similar).

After your computer restarts,

- press F8 to get to the Windows recover menu
- highlight "Repair your computer"
- Highlight "Fix"
- If it asks you here for a keyboard go ahead and comply and hit "Next"
- Here, near the top, there should be an option near the top that says something to the effect of "fix start up" or "repair boot".  This is the option you are after.  Click next and it will patch your boot process.

If things still don't look right, this means the instructions from support.microsoft.com were not followed correctly.

**Do not** under any circumstances do: `Attrib –h –s –r boot.ini.saved Copy boot.ini.saved boot.ini`

support.microsoft.com explains:

> "Note: Follow these steps only when the previous installation is Windows XP or Windows 2000."

You mentioned that you were restoring a previous *Windows 7* installation, so the above command does not apply to you.